# Why did Gandalf's soul leave his body after defeating the Balrog?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gandalf, the-two-towers

After defeating the Balrog on Zirakzigil, the summit of Celebdil above Moria, Gandalf's soul left his body as if he died, and went to Valinor. Why did Gandalf do that? Did he actually die? If so, what would be the cause; Gandalf obviously wasn't injured (except nose bleeding) when he defeated the Balrog and lay down on the summit. I think a possible explanation for Gandalf's death is hypoxia/[HAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-altitude_pulmonary_edema) (Celebdil may be well over 12,000 ft in elevation) in combination with the exhaustion due to the fight and the fact Gandalf was pursuing and fighting the Balrog for many days without or with little rest.

Comment: Why do you say he wasn't injured? He'd just been battling a powerful being for days, after falling down a huge chasm, why wouldn't he be injured?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because he _doesn't_ have any injuries except nose bleeding. If he had below his cloth, the cloth would be torn there. Also, he was able to slay the Balrog which doesn't look like someone who would die soon, but he could have because of the effects of hypoxia and exhaustion.

Comment: Maybe he died of nosebleed.

Comment: @user14111 One does not simply die of nosebleed but what you mean perhaps is that the summit is at an elevation where air is too thin for wounds to get healed. In that case, with continued nose bleeding yes it may be possible. But did Gandalf even actually die or was it more like a spiritual voyage without "proper" dying?

Comment: Perhaps the most notorious victim of a fatal nosebleed was Attila the Hun. Not everybod believes the nosebleed story; some suspect he was murdered.

Comment: @user14111 According to the myth, Attila suffocated from the blood because the blood ran in the other direction (down the throat) in his position.

Comment: The book doesn't say anything about a nosebleed - is that based on the movies? (Gandalf could also have had severe internal injuries,which might have been hidden by his clothing.)

Comment: @MattGutting https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uLqps3SgvI&ab_channel=%EA%99%AE

Comment: @MattGutting He was physically powerful enough to slay the Balrog, a fact that doesn't speak in favor of having lethal injuries. As for external ones his clothing would be torn where any wounds would be.

Comment: @AragornElessar I might be physically powerful enough to defeat a boar, but a good headbutt, surely could split my liver. Physically powerful enough absolutely doesn't mean you are not going to be injured in any (extreme) way. Wat makes you think he wasn't injured? Notice that the movies aren't reliable sources for these type of question.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid What I meant is at the time Gandalf gave the Balrog the last stab (before the Balrog fell down the cliff) he was strong enough to do it and didn't look injured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know it is possible to give someone a mortal wound and still die before them?

I once read about an park in Africa where a teenage elephant was acting aggressive and dangerous and a professional hunter was sent to shoot him.  The hunter never returned, and a search found both of them dead.  They had mortally wounded each other.

General Urah Galusha Pennypacker was shot at the capture of Fort Fisher on January 18, 1865.  Pennypacker unexpectedly survived, but his eventual death on October 1, 1916 – over 50 years later – was caused by complications from that and lesser Civil War wounds.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galusha_Pennypacker

And I have read that Pennypacker was conscious while lying on the ground apparently dead, and later told an interviewer how his soldiers killed the Rebel who had shot him.  So that is an example of someone outliving by over 50 years the person who gave him a mortal wound.

Gandalf fell for probably a distance of miles, fought the balrog, chased the balrog, climbed up many miles of stairs to the top of the mountain, and fought the balrog for days before finally killing it.  Most of the events mentioned would kill a normal mortal human from injuries or the cumulative exhaustion from the activity.

Gandalf was an ainu embodied in human form, but his body was much weaker than a normal ainu body, being a real living body, and so it was much easier to hurt and kill than a typical ainu body, even though it was probably much tougher and harder to kill than a typical human body.

So I find it easy to believe that Gandalf and the balrog mortally wounded each other early in their conflict, but were tough enough to keep fighting for hours or days before finally succumbing.

Gandalf said that if any people had seen the battle from far off they would have reported flashes o flight like lightening.

So maybe Gandalf and the balrog zapped each other with the Middle-Earth equivalent of force lightning.  In *Return of the Jedi* the Emperor zapped Luke Skywalker with force lightening, torturing him, but left no visible signs of it.  And then the Emperor zapped Darth Vader with force lightening, "forcing" Vader to die, without leaving much of a visible mark on Vader's armor.

And it seems quite possible to me that the magical flashes of light that were used in the battle with the balrog could mortally wound someone without leaving any visible wounds or tearing any clothing.

Comment: You're right, there really came lightning out of (or to) Gandalf's sword during the Zirakzigil fight.

Comment: There was a scottish lord (forgot his name) that had attached the head of his enemy to the sadle of his horse. While riding back home, the teeth of the head bounced against the back of his leg, creating a wound which he died from a few days later.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid - That would be Sigurd Eysteinsson, or Sigurd the Mighty, the Second Earl of Orkney. See Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigurd_Eysteinsson), or any credible search engine.